# Set SpriteBatch color (for tinting) affects all drawing

Tags: java, sprite, libgdx, tint, spritebatch

I created a `AnimatedSprite` class, that draw a specific `TextureRegion`. Sometimes I need a tint color effect, so I set (this.color is a `Color` field of my `AnimatedSprite`):

```
super.draw(batch, parentAlpha);

batch.setColor(this.color);
batch.draw(this.frames[this.currentFrame], x, y, originX, originY, width, height, scaleX, scaleY, rotation)
batch.setColor(Color.WHITE);
```

However, when I have an `AnimatedSprite`'s color set to black or any color, everything else has that color tint. I even try to `flush()`, end the batch and begin a new one, etc... but nothing seems to work.

Please help me apply the tint effect correctly. I will appreciate any idea.

Comment: This is the body of the AnimatedSprite `draw` method?  It looks right, and looks like the [Image.java](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/blob/master/gdx/src/com/badlogic/gdx/scenes/scene2d/ui/Image.java#L118) draw method.  Maybe something else?  Is this.color used elsewhere?

Comment: @P.T. I also looked at `Image` class after had seen your comment. The `Image` class doesn't even reset the batch's color, so I tried remove it in my code. `this.color` is not used elsewhere, and I also give the r g b value instead of entire color instance. However, my entire screen is still tint by a color.

Comment: @P.T. Thank you for your hint. I found the problem. Because when initializing, I set my Sprite's color to Color.WHITE (of libgdx), so every of my AnimatedSprite are pointing to the same color!

Comment: I've done that, too.  I've added an answer so that others that come along will see this is answered.  If you have a chance add a bit of your code that "sets color to black", too.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Beware shared mutable [`Color`](http://libgdx.l33tlabs.org/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/graphics/Color.html) objects!  If you do:

```
this.color = Color.WHITE;
```

And then mutate `this.color` later, you will be mutating `Color.WHITE` which is generally the wrong thing!   :)

Always make a copy when constructing a `Color` object that you will mutate:

```
this.color = new Color(Color.WHITE);
```

Many objects in libGDX are mutable like this (whereas similar objects in a regular Java library would be immutable) because libGDX is (rightfully) very concerned about GC overhead.

Answer (score 1):

Rather than use

```
this.color = new Color(Color.WHITE);
```

you could use:

```
batch.setColor(Color.WHITE.tmp());
```

This will create a temporary copy of the white color and seems slightly cleaner to me.

Comment: Color.WHITE.tmp() does not exist in libgdx 1.9.6

Comment: It is .cpy() in latest versions. I believe the best practice is to explicitly set the color before each call (or calls using the same color) to batch.draw().